# Stored Procedures IN mySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to convert hours to minutes using Stored Procedures in MySQL. For example,I am getting the output as 3 hour 15 minutes . I need to convert it as 195 minutes. I tried using multiple cases but nothing worked out for me.. Can you please help me if you have any code to solve this???

Comment: Why you need a stored procedure for it. Simply multiply hours with 60 and add minutes, you will have your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply  Hatim Stovewala! But ,actually the scenario is I will get   output as xx hour xx minutes in a database field. I need to convert it into minutes and store it in another field. So I need code for this scenario.

Comment: @Vivek Varma please share the table structure and some example data as formatted text.

Comment: Thanks Raymond, I got the solution and defined the function for the above requirement. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Function for this purpose.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `toMinutes` 
(
    hour INT,
    minute INT
)
RETURNS INTEGER
BEGIN

    DECLARE result INT;

    SET result = (hour * 60) + minute;

    RETURN result;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Call the function:

```
SELECT toMinutes(1,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked on the requirement and able to create a function successfully as follows!!!

```
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[BUSINESS_DURATION_MINTS_FN]    Script Date: 10/17/2017 12:22:12 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[BUSINESS_DURATION_MINTS_FN]
(@string varchar(100) )
RETURNS INT 
AS



BEGIN
 DECLARE  @total_mints INT
 DECLARE  @hours INT
 DECLARE  @Mints INT
 IF @string IS NOT NULL
 BEGIN
 SET @string = REPLACE(UPPER(@string),'HOURS','HOUR')
 SET @string = REPLACE(UPPER(@string),'MINUTES','MINUTE')
IF  ((CHARINDEX(UPPER('HOUR'),UPPER(@string))!=0)  AND (CHARINDEX(UPPER('MINUTE'),UPPER(@string))!= 0)) 

   BEGIN
   SET  @hours = CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(@string,1, (CHARINDEX(UPPER('HOUR'), UPPER(@string))-2))) 
   SET  @Mints = CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(@string,(CHARINDEX(UPPER('HOUR'),UPPER(@string))+4),(CHARINDEX(UPPER('MINUTE'),UPPER(@string))-(CHARINDEX(UPPER('HOUR'), UPPER(@string))+5))))
   END


   IF  ((CHARINDEX(UPPER('HOUR'),UPPER(@string))=0)  AND (CHARINDEX(UPPER('MINUTE'),UPPER(@string))!= 0)) 
   BEGIN
  SET  @hours = 0
   SET  @Mints = CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(@string,1, (CHARINDEX(UPPER('MINUTE'), UPPER(@string))-2)))
   END


  IF  ((CHARINDEX(UPPER('HOUR'),UPPER(@string))!=0)  AND (CHARINDEX(UPPER('MINUTE'),UPPER(@string))=0)) 
   BEGIN
   SET  @hours = CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(@string,1, (CHARINDEX(UPPER('HOUR'), UPPER(@string))-2))) 
  SET  @Mints = 0
   END

   IF  ((CHARINDEX(UPPER('HOUR'),UPPER(@string))= 0)  AND (CHARINDEX(UPPER('MINUTE'),UPPER(@string))=0)) 
   BEGIN
   SET  @hours = 0    
   SET  @Mints = 0
   END

   SET  @total_mints = @hours*60 + @Mints


  END
  IF  @string IS NULL
  BEGIN
  SET @total_mints = NULL

  END
     RETURN @total_mints

END


GO
```

Comment: I am not able to call this function in a stored procedure. Can anyone help me in this??

Comment: What error you are getting when you call the function from SP?